# Выполнение system: как дождаться завершения?

Tags: pthread, c++, linux

ОС - linux. Нужно дождаться выполнения команды system в потоке. Происходит примерно так:

Создаются потоки:

```
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

for(int i=0; i < threads_count; i++)
{
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, wrkthread, (void *)i);

  if(rc) 
      {
        cout << "ERROR1:" << rc << " ID:" << i << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "Thread started" << endl;
      }

  rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
  if (rc)
  {
    cout << "ERROR2 #" << i;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

и сам поток:

```
void *wrkthread(void *threadid)
{
...
    system('./myscript.sh');
...
}
```

Нужно чтобы поток дожидался выполнения скрипта (а это секунд 10-15, каждый раз по разному), записывал время и только потом закрывал поток

Спасибо!

Comment: А поток всегда будет ждать завершения скрипта, выполняемого в system(). 

--

Вообще-то Вы тут pthread_join() похоже не в том месте написали. Скорее всего Вы хотели в цикле запустить threads_count потоков (в параллель), а потом дождаться их завершения.

Тогда нужно 2 цикла. В первом запускаете потоки, а во втором ждете, т.е. именно в нем надо вызывать pthread_join().

Кстати, по умолчанию поток создается PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE, поэтому можно просто писать

     pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, wrkthread, (void *)i);

если Вы, конечно, другие атрибуты не модифицируете.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

ответ вынесен из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/254239/#comment254241_254239):

---

А поток всегда будет ждать завершения скрипта, выполняемого в `system()`.

Вообще-то Вы тут `pthread_join()`, похоже, не в том месте написали. Скорее всего Вы хотели в цикле запустить `threads_count` потоков (в параллель), а потом дождаться их завершения. Тогда нужно 2 цикла:

В первом запускаете потоки, а во втором ждете, т.е. именно в нем надо вызывать `pthread_join()`.

Кстати, по умолчанию поток создается `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE`, поэтому можно просто писать:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], 0, wrkthread, (void *)i);
```

если Вы, конечно, другие атрибуты не модифицируете.